# WIndows 11 - always waking up - wake source is "Device -PCI-to-PCI Bridge"

Tags: sleep, windows-11, pci

My Windows 11 desktop PC keeps waking up from sleep.  Looking at the Event Viewer this is the event that happens over and over:

```
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2022‎-‎08‎-‎14T00:49:10.202886500Z
Wake Time: ‎2022‎-‎08‎-‎14T00:51:52.856075400Z

Wake Source: Device -PCI-to-PCI Bridge
```

I don't know what this is, or how I disable it so the machine will keep sleeping and not be awake all night.  Machine specs:

- Windows 11 Pro
- MSI Tomahawk x570
- Ryzen 5950x
- RTX3080
- 32GB DDR4 3600

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/981978/computer-waking-up-due-to-some-pci-device

Comment: You can open device manager and search for this bridge (select it). Then switch to View Device by Connection to see what devices are connected to this bridge.